# Enable automatic syntax highlighting for Swift

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

The question [What design pattern would help me make my factory more generic](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/386331/173647) is tagged [swift-language](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/swift-language) but syntax highlighting is not applied to the code block. Can one of the ♦ moderators please enable *automatic* syntax highlighting for this tag (the setting is configurable on [this page](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/tags/swift-language/info))? I've now suggested an edit to enable it, but it would be nice to have this done automatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did this thing. Not sure if it's retroactive, but it should be set going forward.

Comment: [Yes, it is retroactive.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/304077/173647) Thanks!