# Enable automatic syntax highlighting for [haskell]

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, syntax-highlighting

I just approved [this suggested edit](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/229296) adding syntax highlighting to Haskell code in an answer. That would not be necessary if the [haskell](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/haskell) tag had automatic syntax highlighting; ♦ moderators can change this. See [this previous request of mine for the Swift language](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8858/173647).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been done. I applied the `lang-hs` code language for the default syntax highlighting for the tag.